# What did Madoka wish for in the original timeline?

Tags: madoka-magica

I just watched the show - Madoka spends most of it trying to figure out a good wish to make.

One episode shows Homura in presumably the original timeline, where she's just a shy new kid and Madoka is already a magical girl along with Mami, which means Madoka had in fact made a wish in this timeline. Is it ever mentioned what did she wish for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

She wished the cat in the opening (named Amy) to be saved from being run over by a car. This is revealed in the Drama CD 1.

More info about wishes in the series: https://wiki.puella-magi.net/Wish_theories#.E2.9C.94.C2.A0Timeline_1_-_Save_that_cat.21

More info about the Drama CD 1: https://wiki.puella-magi.net/Drama_CD_1

Comment: Sounds like Madoka alright lol.

Comment: You bet, in another one of Homura's timelines, Mami joked around that she'll have her wish for a huge cake lol! I think it's a clue to her timid and bashful personality.

Comment: I wish they release a "video" version of this drama audio CD!  :P